# PHP, SESSION array is not updating properly

Tags: php, session, get

Ok I'm having a really hard time with this `shoppingcart.php` code that I'm trying to write. I'll try to break it down so it's easy to understand:

- First I use `$_GET` to get an `itemID` and quantity from a separate
  `store.php` file.
- I initialize a `SESSION` array like so: `$_SESSION['cart'] =
  array();`
- I check to see if the quantity and `itemID` is valid and if it is I
  add them to the session array.
- I display the everything in the session array in a table.

I'm having two problems.

**First,** The session array is not saving the old item if I go back and pick additional items.**

**Second,** if I go straight the `cart.php` file to `"view my cart"` it says there is nothing at all in there. It only displays something if I fill out the form in `store.php` and hit submit. And then it only displays one thing.

Here is the **[the code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5226210)** (**both cart.php and store.php**):

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: You dont need to initialize $_SESSION['cart'] = array(); , $_SESSION is already an array

Comment: and post your code for good suggestion

Comment: What does redirect_if_offline(); do?

Comment: @sandip That's a bit misleading as a comment: `$_SESSION['cart'] = array()` initializes *the `cart` element of $_SESSION* as an array, not $_SESSION. Try `<?php session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION); $_SESSION['cart'] = array(); var_dump($_SESSION); session_destroy();`

Comment: Sandip provided the correct answer. The problem was that I was initializing $_SESSION['cart'] as an array. Once I took out the line "$_SESSION['car'] = array();" Everything worked. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

*i think looking in to this , may help :*

```
$product_id = $_GET['id']; //the product id from the URL
$action = $_GET['action']; //the action from the URL

//if there is an product_id and that product_id doesn't exist display an error message
if($product_id && !productExists($product_id)) {
    die("Error. Product Doesn't Exist");
}

switch($action) { //decide what to do

    case "add":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++; //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id
    break;

    case "remove":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]--; //remove one from the quantity of the product with id $product_id
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]); //if the quantity is zero, remove it completely (using the 'unset' function) - otherwise is will show zero, then -1, -2 etc when the user keeps removing items.
    break;

    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION['cart']); //unset the whole cart, i.e. empty the cart.
    break;

}

?>
```

from [here](http://jameshamilton.eu/content/simple-php-shopping-cart-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Probable answer to your questions

First :
   To keep all values use $_SESSION['cart'][] instead of $_SESSION['cart'] ; make it multidimensional otherwise it will overwrite your values

SECOND :
   How will cart.php show items ? 
      you are initialising $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    at begining of page .. It is emptying your old values.. if you come directly to cart.php

Hope it helps you